# Recursion to Find Cheapest Solution

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have this problem to do:

> Write a function using Recursion to do the following: You are the manager in a small factory. You have 7 workers and 7 jobs to be done. Each worker is assigned one and only one job. Each worker demands different pay for each job. (E.g.: Worker Archie demands $10 for welding, $15 for carpentry, etc. Worker Jughead demands $12 for welding, $5 for carpentry, etc.) Find the job-assignment which works out cheapest for you.

I have created these eight classes about how much each worker demands:
A probably unnecessary superclass

```
public class Workers
{
public int doCarpentry()
    {return 0;}
public int doWelding()
    {return 0;}
public int doMechanic()
    {return 0;}
public int doCleaning()
    {return 0;}
public int doDishes()
    {return 0;}
public int doPlumbing()
    {return 0;}
public int doCashier()
    {return 0;}       
}
```

The other seven all look like this:

```
public class Jennifer extends Workers
{
public int doCarpentry()
    {return 10;}
public int doWelding()
    {return 10;}
public int doMechanic()
    {return 12;}
public int doCleaning()
    {return 12;}
public int doDishes()
    {return 8;}
public int doPlumbing()
    {return 9;}
public int doCashier()
    {return 10;}       
}

public class Linda extends Workers 
{
public int doCarpentry()
    {return 9;}
public int doWelding()
    {return 13;}
public int doMechanic()
    {return 10;}
public int doCleaning()
    {return 9;}
public int doDishes()
    {return 12;}
public int doPlumbing()
    {return 14;}
public int doCashier()
    {return 9;}       
}
```

I'm trying to create a Manager class and I am completely confused. I don't even know where to begin, especially because I am required to use recursion. Please help!

Comment: What's unnecessary is creating a type for each employee. What when you'll have 200 employees ? Having to compile each time you hire someone will get boring.

Comment: The recursion on this problem mean to create a function to return all possible (7!) combinations of workers/jobs thus ssolving the problem by "brute force". Concerning the classes I don't see why do you need to create a manager class, worker and job classes are engouh

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematical point of view you're trying to minimize a system of 7 equations

```
10c1+10w+12m+12c2+ 8d+ 9p+10c3  //jennifer
 9c1+13w+10m+ 9c2+12d+14p+ 9c3  //linda
...
```

where

```
c1 is carpentry
w is welding
...
```

and where each variabile must be equal to "1" only once in the whole system, "0" all the other times.

Try starting from this. 
You representation, furtermore, is not adequate. You can't have a class for each person.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a few tips:

You can greatly simplify the state representation here. The easiest to work with here is a 7x7 matrix of costs, each line representing a worker, each column a job to be done, each cell the cost. Alternatively, you can create a class worker, etc. But PLEASE don't go creating a class and 7 methods for each instance of a worker.

Now, the real problem is to FIND an optimal solution. Pick the permutations of work to be done by each worker. You clearly have 7! options here (pick 1 out of 7 jobs for the first worker, 1 out of the 6 remaining for the second, etc).

That's where recursion comes in. You can make the first choice, then call your method again to make the second choice, and so on. When all 7 choices have been made, record the cost if it is the best so far. The let the recursion go back one step and make a different choice. You will also need an array of booleans to flag which jobs have already been picked, to avoid repetitions.

I'll leave the actual code to you, since its an exercise.